Can you help me find this short horror story I heard on Otis Jiry's Scary Stories Told in the Dark podcast?
The story is about a man who digs a hole near a Union camp during the American Civil War. He is planning to try and assassinate a Union general by hiding in it and covering himself with a camouflaged sheet that he can see through. He apparently digs the ditch underneath some sort of dead tree? Or a bridge; I don't remember. But, as he is waiting in the hole, he starts to hallucinate that there are a pair of eyes staring back at him. He kills the general and uses the hiding spot to hide from the Union soldiers.
I remember hearing this story on Otis Jiry's Scary Stories Told in the Dark podcast. Can you help me find this story? I remember listening to it about 2-3 years ago.

Did this story contain any genuine sci-fi or fantasy elements? If so, what were they?

@LogicDictates yes it did in some sort of way, there was some sort of super natural creature who kills the guy at the end. The whole story it varies between him either hallucinating or there actually being supernatural entites
